# Weird URLs being access by Googlebot

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, crawl-errors

Lately I've been seing all sorts of strange URLs show up as errors in my Webmaster tools account, but they're URLs that don't actually exist on my site, nor are linked from the pages that Google claims they're linked from.

```
URL                                 Response Code   Detected
yR3kna/5RfA4+ndtn/X4zcevudMlXbqbIrnPbH9irw= 404     9/16/12
OK4iaOVdr6Ocjmz+u1kuR5Q486mhDo/e45nwjl2+y8= 404     9/9/12
pxGz/oHEA0BS8U3VFBzJcZnnIHMsFXb3/rIxMxh2ws= 404     9/16/12
Af8tbvQ0HniIpf53I8Txz1hM1/JxxrFQxgqPuErWII= 404     9/9/12
7Bk7c0LDmm4PHyTjml017EGwNNPCn/p/0xMSWWPDic= 404     9/16/12
umCwnDvTE8ybpUB19MIb+VRj5xRJncyYGGfAQ2Mxn0= 404     9/1/12
# etc...
```

Do you know how to make these stop? It's not at all clear to me why it would be going to these URLs in the first place.

Comment: can you post your site url?

Comment: Related: [Why is Google Webmaster Tools crawling invalid URLS and showing 500 errors?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28257/why-is-google-webmaster-tools-crawling-invalid-urls-and-showing-500-errors)

Comment: Looks like base64 encoded text. If it is the sample URLs are incomplete and not to debug.

Answer (score 1):

If you can check your web server logs, you can block the user-agent or IP where they are coming from, for instance with the .htaccess file

Comment: They're coming from 66.249.73.138, which is owned by Google